# IndexError: list index out of range: idk where

Tags: python, python-3.8

Although compilation works successfully I get an error: IndexError: list index out of range

The function takes as argument a sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the same value next to each other and preserving the original order of elements.
The code i write:

```
def fnc(l, a):
   print(l)
   if l[a] == l[a+1]:
      del l[a]
      return fnc(l, 0)
   elif l[a] != l[a+1]:
      return fnc(l, a+1)
   elif a == len(l):
      return l

def unique_in_order(txt):
   list = []
   for i in txt:
      list  += [i]
   return fnc(list, 0)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: provide some sample input that you are trying to give.

Comment: unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']

Comment: it looks like you are trying to something with recursion and forgot to add a base case to exit the recursion. can you elobarate little more what you want to achive?

probably tell us a sample input and output.

Comment: i took a base case like: elif a == len(l): return l

Comment: input is a string like "AAaBBBsBSSBJJK" it must output "AaBsBSBJK"

Comment: what compilation? this is python ....

Comment: don't use built in function names as name of variables.

Comment: any time you use `l[a+1]:` in your code you could be out of bounds - check it or handle the IndexError

Comment: this error is occuring because your'e iterating over a list while deleting indexes from it, which eventually causes your for loop to bump into a non existent index. the best solution to deal with this is to create a copy of your list, iterate over the copy, and delete the corresponding indexes you want from the original list

Comment: The simplest way is to assume a string of "a" and play it through ... you compare a 1 len string and access l[1] ... which is out of bounds....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy like using recursion just for the sake of it. Python is known for providing many ways to solve the problem but good programmers are known for writing simple code so everyone can understand.

Now coming to your problem. You just need to check if the next word is same or not, if not then store the current word.

```
input_string = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'

# return string without next duplicates and in order

output_list = []
for char in range(len(input_string)):
    if char == len(input_string)-1:
        output_list.append(input_string[char])
    else:
        if input_string[char] != input_string[char+1]:
            output_list.append(input_string[char])

output_string = ''.join(output_list)
print(output_string)
#ABCDAB
```

Comment: thank you, next time I will try not to complicate my code